# Error while localizing Javascript content in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, localization

I AM getting the following error:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: gettext`

I have added the following in my `urls.py`:

```
js_info_dict = { 'domain': 'djangojs', 'packages': ('my_project_name',), }
urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict), )
```

I marked the string for localization as :

```
var lingualText = gettext("Are you sure you want to delete the photo?");  
var statusConfirm = confirm(lingualText);
```

I have added the following line in my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
```

To generate the language file for the text inside javascript file, I use the following command:

```
python /usr/bin/django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l de
```

I am able to generate the `djangojs.po` file for the desired language. And I also get all the strings marked in the JS file. When I see the output in `Firebug`, I see the above error i.e.:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: gettext`

Can anybody tell me where am I going wrong? Am I having the problem with the path for `jsi18n` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`getext()` is provided by the `{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}` script, so make sure it is included before your own code is, e.g.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
    <!-- gettext() is now available -->
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}my_script_using_gettext.js"></script>
    ...
```